# Reserved Memory Equals Shared Memory but Memory is Never Reserved

Tags: c, memory-management, shared-memory, mmap

I am currently editing a program I inherited to be able to work with 23 GB files. As such, to maintain low memory, I am using `mmap` to load arrays which I had created in a previous program. However, I load these arrays, and then enter into a function and the shared and reserved memory spikes, even though I do not believe I ever allocate anything. When running, the memory starts at 0 and then quickly increases to 90% (~36GB as I have 40GB of ram) and stays there. Eventually, I start needing memory (less than 30GB) and the program then gets killed.

Usually, I would suspect that this issue would be due to allocation, or that I was somehow allocating memory. However, I am not allocating any memory (although I am reading in `mmap`ed files).

The curious thing is that the memory reserved is equal to the amount of memory shared (see attached screenshot).

[image: Output]

The functions that I wrote to access mmaped arrays:

```c
double* loadArrayDouble(ssize_t size, char* backupFile, int *filedestination) {
    *filedestination = open(backupFile, O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0644);
    if (*filedestination < 0) {
        perror("open failed");
        exit(1);
    }
    // make sure file is big enough
    if (lseek(*filedestination,size*sizeof(double), SEEK_SET) == -1) {
        perror("seek to len failed");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    if (lseek(*filedestination, 0, SEEK_SET) == -1) {
        perror("seek to 0 failed");
        exit(1);
    }

    double *array1 = mmap(NULL, size*sizeof(double), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, *filedestination, 0);
    if (array1 == MAP_FAILED) {
        perror("mmap failed");
        exit(1);
    }

    return array1;
}
```

Please let me know if there is any other code to include.. It appears that the memory increases significantly even though `double* file1 = loadArrayDouble(SeqSize, "/home/HonoredTarget/file1", &fileIT);` is called multiple times (for each of the 6 arrays)

Comment: What's the problem? What is the RSS? (maybe you are looking at the wrong metrics)

Comment: Thank you for the comment! Checking right now

Comment: Not sure if I did it correctly, but I ran `cat /proc/8904/status` where 8904 was the pid and it  said `RssFile: 36050208 kB` so it seems that it is about the same.. RssAnon was 104 kb and RssShmem was 0kb

Comment: Test with smaller arrays (or check the syslog) Maybe you are meeting the OOM-killer.

Comment: Yeah. I think that I am running into that, although this happens later when I start to need more memory (and actually allocate). Based off of my output logs, it seems that I don't run into those spots until after the memory as plateaued at 90% which is the weird part

Comment: You must be new to mmap/virtual memory.

Comment: Yep! I learned about it just recently (for this project). Should have added that in the beginning sorry.

Comment: Strong advise to test first on a toy-problem. And: do some reading. mmap() is not a panaceum.

Comment: Yeah. I did a little testing before and I thought that I had gotten a good hang of this (this is the third part of the analysis and I was able to successfully use mmap in the other two) so I don't know why it is going wrong

Comment: Sorry, that was a bit sloppy. I kept thinking of other things to say. I'm done now :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Res" is short for "resident", not "reserved". Resident memory refers to the process memory which the kernel happens to have resident at the moment; the virtual memory system might drop a resident page at any moment, so it's not in any way a limitation. However, the kernel attempts not to swap out pages which seem to be active. The OOM killer will act if your process is churning too many pages in and out of memory. If you use data sequentially, then it usually doesn't matter how much you have mmap'ed, because only the recent pages will be resident. But if you skip around in the memory, reading a bit here and writing a bit there, then you'll create more churn. That seems like what is happening.

"shr" (shared) memory does in fact refer to memory which could be shared with another process (whether or not it actually is shared with another process). The fact that you use `MAP_SHARED` means that it is not surprising that all of your mmap'ed pages are shared. You need `MAP_SHARED` if your program modifies the data in the file, which I guess it does.

The "virt" (virtual) column measures how much of your address spaced you've actually mapped (including memory mapped to anonymous backing storage by whatever dynamic allocation library you're using.) 170G seems   a bit high to me. If you have six 23GB files mapped simultaneously, that would be 138GB. But perhaps those numbers were just estimates. Anyway, it doesn't matter that much, as long as you're within the virtual memory limits you've set. (Although page tables do occupy real memory, so there is some effect.)

Memory mapping does not save you memory, really. When you mmap a file, the contents of the file still need to be read into memory in order for your program to use the data. The big advantage to mmap is that you don't have to futz around with allocating buffers and issuing read calls. Also, there is no need to copy data from the kernel buffer into which the file is read. So it can be a lot easier and more efficient, but not always; it depends a lot on the precise access pattern.

One thing to note: the following snippet does not do what the comment says it does:

```
    // make sure file is big enough
    if (lseek(*filedestination,size*sizeof(double), SEEK_SET) == -1) {
        perror("seek to len failed");
        exit(1);
    }
```

`lseek` only sets the file position for the next read or write operation. If the file does not extend to that point, you'll get an EOF indication when you read, or the file will be extended (sparsely) if you write. So there's really not much point. If you want to check the file size, use `stat`. Or make sure you read at least one byte after doing the seek.

There's also not a lot of point using `O_CREAT` in the `open` call, since if the file doesn't exist and thus gets created, it will have size 0, which is presumably an error. Leaving `O_CREAT` off means the `open` call will fail if the file doesn't exist, which is likely what you want.

Finally, if you are not actually modifying the file contents, don't mmap with `PROT_WRITE`. `PROT_READ` pages are a lot easier for the kernel to deal with, because they can just be dropped and read back in later. (For writable pages, the kernel keeps track of the fact that the page has been modified, but if you aren't planning on writing and you don't allow modification, that makes the kernel's task a bit easier.)

Comment: Thank you! I will make sure to fix that and that makes a lot of sense. However, I guess wouldn't it be the case that when I allocate more memory (for a 50 x 2 matrix a little while later) that the mmaped memory starts being swapped out? This doesn't seem to be the case but I am probably missing something.

Comment: @HonoredTarget: Yes, the memory will be swapped out. And it is being swapped out (or not swapped in) since your resident set is a lot less than the total size of the files. However, if your access pattern really skips around a lot (or reads sequentially over and over again very quickly) then the disk might not keep up. That's particularly true if you are modifying the file, because modified pages have to be written out before the kernel buffer can be recycled, which is a lot more time-consuming.

Comment: Ah. I updated the files where I only read (Side note: do you know if memcpy would work with mmap?). However, I guess I don't know if it would be enough to make it kill it? Makes more sense why memory is increasing though.

Comment: @HonoredTarget: The other thing is that the kernel doesn't swap pages out if it doesn't need to, even if the page hasn't been referred to for a long time. If no other process on your machine is trying to use memory, then the resident set will grow to fill most of your RAM. If much of that memory hasn't been used recently, then the resident set will rapidly shrink as soon as some other process tries to work.

Comment: @HonoredTarget: once a file has been mmaped, it acts just as if it were in memory. So memcpy works just the same as a simple assignment. (These are among the reasons why mmap is convenient.)

Comment: Neat. Also good because otherwise I would have a lot of rewriting to do :)

Comment: @HonoredTarget: One more thing: if you are modifying the files, you should use `msync` and verify that it returns without an error before you unmap the file. There is no other way to know if the data has actually been correctly committed to disk. (You might not be able to do anything about the failure, but you can at least log a message.)

Comment: If you don't mind (also I realize that this may be unanswerable) but do you think that the reason it got killed was because of mmap? or when i try and allocate new memory? Its unfortunate because the kernel has to do so much work that getting to the problem spot takes a long time

Comment: @honoredTarget: i don't know. You'd have to look at the OOM logs and they're not exactly easy to parse. One possibility is that you have fragmented your memory (perhaps by doing lots of noncontiguous modifications) and then you ask for a block of memory which requires an expanded page table. Since page tables have to be contiguous in real memory, memory fragmentation may make it impossible to allocate a larger page table, which will trigger the OOM killer.

Comment: I think it's going to be a challenge, but you could start by searching for something like "linux  kernel memory fragmentation" and see if you can find some good advice.

Comment: Will do! Thank you so much for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

Since you are (apparently) getting your process killed by the OOM killer, even though the memory you are using is MAP_SHARED (so never requires backing store -- it is auotmatically backed by the file), it would appear you are running your linux with no swap space, which is a bad idea if you have large mapped files like this, as it will cause processes to get killed whenever your resident memory approaches your physical memory.  So the obvious solution would be to add a swap file -- even a small amount (1-2GB) will avoid the OOM killer problem.  There are lots of tutorials online about how to add a swapfile in linux.  You can look [here](https://itsfoss.com/create-swap-file-linux/) or [here](https://linuxize.com/post/create-a-linux-swap-file/) or search for yourself.

If for some reason you don't want to add a swapfile, you may be able to reduce the frequency of getting killed by increasing the "swappiness" of your system -- this will cause the kernel to drop pages of your mmapped files more readily, thus reducing the likelyhood of getting into an OOM situation.  You do this by increasing the vm.swappiness parameter either in your sysctl.conf file (for bootup) or by writing a new value to your /proc/sys/vm/swappiness file.